# Java using a while loop to load user input into an array

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering how to load up an array (with user input) using a while loop. The code below prints a 0.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int[] myArray = new int[10];
    System.out.printf("enter a value>>");
    while (scan.nextInt() > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i > 0; i++) {
            myArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.printf("enter a value>>");
    }
    System.out.printf("array index 2 is %d", myArray[2]);
}
```

Comment: for(i=0; i > 0 ; i++) will never get satisfied and hence your array doesnot get populated

Comment: walk through your code in your mind. Visualize what it is doing at each step in its progression.

Comment: @nem - Looking for rep points, are we?  :-) :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things wrong with your code:

First of all

```
while(scan.nextInt() > 0){
```

`Scanner.nextInt()` returns an `int` from your standard input so you actually have to pick up that value. You are checking here what the user typed but then **not using it** at all and storing the next thing that the user types by saying:

```
myArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
```

You don't really need the outer `while` loop, just use the `for` loop, its enough.

However, your `for` loop is off as well:

```
for(i = 0; i > 0; i++){
```

It starts at `i` equal to 0 and runs while `i` is greater than 0. This means it will never actually run the code within the loop because 0 is never greater than 0. And if it did run (you started it at some number < 0), you would end up in an infinite loop because your condition `i > 0` is **always** true for positive numbers.

Change the loop to:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
```

Now, your loop could look like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){                  // do this 10 times
    System.out.printf("enter a value>>"); // print a statement to the screen 
    myArray[i] = scan.nextInt();          // read an integer from the user and store it into the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one other way to do it

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
List list = new ArrayList();
while(true){
    System.out.println("Enter a value to store in list");
    list.add(scan.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Enter more value y to continue or enter n to exit");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ans = s.nextLine();
    if(ans.equals("n"))
        break;
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr=new int[4];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
        arr[i]=input.nextInt();         
    }

    for(i=0;i<4;i++) 
    {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope this code helps.